# Perl call a system command and keep the script running at the same time

Tags: linux, perl, system

I am running a perl script that does a logical check and if certain conditions been met. Example: If it's been over a certain length of time I want to run a system() command on a linux server that runs another script that updates that data. script that updates the file takes 10-15 seconds, with the current amount of files it has to go through, but can be up to 30 seconds during peak times of the month.

I want the perl script to run and if it has to run the system() command, I don't want it to wait for the system() to finish before finishing the rest of the script. What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please include some example code of what you've done so far? It's helpful to provide as much info as you can on a given question, plus it demonstrates to others that you've done some due diligence prior to asking a question.

Answer (score 5):

System runs a command in the shell, so you can use all of your shell features, including job control. So just stick & at the end of your command thus:

```
system "sleep 30 &";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fork` to create a child process, and then in the child, call your other script using `exec` instead of system.  `exec` will execute your other script in a separate process and return immediately, which will allow the child to finish.  Meanwhile, your parent script can finish what it needs to do and exit as well.

Check [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=683628) out.  It may help you.

There's another good example of how to use fork on [this](https://wiki.bc.net/atl-conf/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20548191) page.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Not intended to be a pun due to publication date, but beware of zombies!
It is a bit tricky, see [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) for details.
However, as far as I understood your problem, you don't need to maintain any relation between the updater and the caller processes. In this case, it is easier to just "fire and forget":

```
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);
use POSIX;

# fork child
unless (fork) {
    # create a new session
    POSIX::setsid();

    # fork grandchild
    unless (fork) {

        # close standard descriptors
        open STDIN, '<', '/dev/null';
        open STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null';
        open STDERR, '>', '/dev/null';

        # run another process
        exec qw(sleep 10);
    }

    # terminate child
    exit;
}
```

In this example, `sleep 10` don't belong to the process' group anymore, so even killing the parent process won't affect the child.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good tutorial about running external programs from Perl (including running background processes) at http://aaroncrane.co.uk/talks/pipes_and_processes/paper.html